# How to (semi-)automatically sync local files with remote devcontainer?

Tags: vscode-remote

## My Goal

I've been using devcontainers in combination with WSL2 for a little while now. But I keep running into issues and besides that I like off-loading resources of my laptop to a server. Moving the containers to a native Linux server would solve my issues.

My ideal situation would be to have a solution that works just like working locally on my Windows laptop (later probably moving to Macbook) but using the facilities of a Linux server (which has systemd and netns) and moving the workload there as well so my laptop doesn't sound like a vacuum cleaner.

## My Journey

I'm trying to setup remote containers as described here: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host

Actually the containers are running fine, I'm using the second storage solution what means I add the following to my .devcontainer.json:

```
"workspaceMount": "source=/home/marvink/code,target=/workspaces,type=bind,consistency=cached"
```

And my workflow currently looks something like this:

- Clone project locally (with .devcontainer already in the project)
- Add workspaceMount above to devcontainer.json
- Clone project on remote (e.g. to /home/marvink/code/new-project)
- Open project locally
- Build and reopen in container
- Work on the files on the remote

## My issue

This works but now I have files on my local drive that never get touched which isn't ideal but not a disaster, the bigger issue is when I want to update the devcontainer. I need to do that locally (in a seperate window), manually need to copy paste that to the remote if I want to commit it to git and off-course I sometimes forget this and try to edit it remotely which is causing a lot of frustration (and sometimes it seems like it does use the remote config, but that might have been a mistake?).

This is why I want to setup rsync both ways to sync changes to files and as a bonus I can edit files locally when I'm offline. In the link it's described how to do it manually but I want it automated so that I can't forget or make mistakes.

From Powershell I'm able to run an rsync command that syncs one-way and I can extend that to sync 2-way:

```
wsl rsync -rlptzv --progress --exclude=.git '$PWD' 'marvink@s-dev01:~/code/new-project'
```

This needs to be ran locally but I can't find a way to do that. I'd need to run a task locally for example, but that isn't possibly when working on a remote (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/168).

The other way around doesn't seem like an option to me as I don't want to expose any ports on my laptop and firewalls would get in the way depending on where I am.

## My question

My workflow still seems a bit convoluted so I'm open to suggestions on that end but any ideas on how to sync my workspace files?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a local version of your code (containing the `.devcontainer` folder) if you're storing that code on the remote server. You should be able to open an ssh target in VScode using the Remote - SSH extension, which is the recommended approach in the [link you added](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host#_connect-using-the-remote-ssh-extension-recommended). The extension Remote - Containers 'stacks' on top of the SSH extension, so once connected over SSH you then connect to the container using the `.devcontainer.json` configuration located on your remote server.

If you don't want to use the extension and use a bind mount + specify docker.host in your `settings.json` file, you can sync code using the approaches in that same article, through SSHFS, docker machine, or rsync.